# MPAndroidChart: how implement zoom Asix X and zoom does not work when scrolling is running

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I’m using MpChartAndroid library 2.2.4, I have a "CombinedChart" with 100 x values (chartXVals) and VisibleXRangeMaximum is 30. When I draw entries force to scroll to the last X:

```
int indexXVal = chartXVals.size() - 1
this.mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(30);
this.mChart.moveViewToX(indexXVal);
this.mChart.setScaleYEnabled(false);
this.mChart.setScaleXEnabled(true);
```

First question - I have two buttons to zoom in / zoom out the Asix X of chart. Unfortunately the methods *zoomIn* / *zoomOut* make zoom from the charts center of viewport of Asix X and Asix Y, then setScaleYEnabled(false) is ignored.
I tried so:

```
float factorScaleX = 1.4 —>  zoom in
float factorScaleX = 0.7 —>  zoom out

PointF center = this.getChart().getViewPortHandler().getContentCenter();
this.getChart().zoom(factorScaleX, 1f, center.x, 0f);
```

Have you another solution?

Second question - When I am scrolling the chart, there is `mDragDecelerationEnabled = true` as default.

The problem is when the scroll action is running, if I do *zoomIn*/*zoomOut* methods the zoom does not run. When the scrolling is finished, the zoom works. 
I noted this behavior doing print Log in `onChartTranslate` method of the listener `OnChartGestureListener`.

how can I resolve it?

Thanks